# Выравнять/выровнять строки

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`А как в Word'e строки выровнять?`

`А как в Word'e строки выравнять?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***выровнять***.

---

Корень -РАВН- используется, когда речь идет о равенстве. Корень -РОВН- используется при речи о ровности чего-л.

---

В данном случае *равенств* нет, зато есть *ровность* (строк).

---

Поэтому верно использовать корень -РОВН-:

*А как строки в Word'е выр**о**внять*?

Comment: В РАН написано по-другому, где *равн — ровн*: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=29#pp29.